# Отображение скрипта в ячейках таблицы

Tags: html, javascript

Хочу сделать таблицу, в которой в каждой ячейке будет отрисованный ява-скрипт, но получается - скрипт за таблицей, как это поправить?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Stars test</title>
<script src='http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="rater.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.rater.packed.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.rater.js'></script>

</head>

<body>
<p>Down stars</p>

<table border="2" bordercolor="red">
<tr>
    <td>
<div id='rating1' class='rating'>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#rating1').rater('ratings.php',

    {maxvalue:30, style: 'basic', curvalue:5}

    );
</script>
</div>
    </td>
    <td>
<div id='rating1' class='rating'>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#rating1').rater('ratings.php',

    {maxvalue:30, style: 'basic', curvalue:5}

    );
</script>
</div>
    </td>
    <td>
<div id='rating1' class='rating'>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#rating1').rater('ratings.php',

    {maxvalue:30, style: 'basic', curvalue:5}

    );
</script>
</div>
    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
<div id='rating1' class='rating'>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#rating1').rater('ratings.php',

    {maxvalue:30, style: 'basic', curvalue:5}

    );
</script>
</div>
    </td>
    <td>
<div id='rating1' class='rating'>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#rating1').rater('ratings.php',

    {maxvalue:30, style: 'basic', curvalue:5}

    );
</script>
</div>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Или все копии одного скрипта в одной ячейке.

Comment: Что значит отрисованный JavaScript?

Comment: Ну там плагин - голосования за картинку, картинки в таблице, под каждой картинкой должен отображаться этот скрипт, а он выводится нужное кол-во раз, но все в первой ячейке.

Comment: Ничего не понятно, пример в студию

Comment: Как-то так, у нас есть таблица, в таблицу 3 ячейке, надо - в каждую ячейку по отображению скрипту. Получается - все 3 скрипта, НО в 1 ячейке.

Answer (score 1):

Какой то у Вас подход кривой. Если эту задачу решать вашим методом, то, например, при наличии на странице 100 картинок - получается 100 кусков кода, что не очень целесообразно. Не проще ли было поступить так:

- Пусть каждая картинка имеет свое уникальное имя id
- Создайте один обработчик, который определяет по какой именно картинке щелкнули, т.е. получает ее имя
- Затем PHP-скрипту нужно передать это имя, где происходит увеличение счетчика голосов за картинку с этим именем.
- Вносите в базу нужные изменения

Comment: Я эту логику понимаю. Тут я просто сижу играюсь с ксс и скриптом, смотрю как работает, но моя же задача - отобразить результат. Предположим, у меня на страничку надо вывести только 3 картинки, картинки в таблице, в каждую ячейку под картинку надо вывести эту систему голосования. Как это сделать?

Comment: Такой вопрос - У Вас результаты голосования где хранятся? В базе? Или вообще не хранятся?

Comment: будет по средствам аджакса хранится в бд, в моей "песочнице", то что я выложил, не где не хранится, у меня проблема с отображением